# LISP: Reversing a dotted list

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp, cons

There is a question in **Common Lisp: A Gentle Introduction**.  The question is to get the *last* element in the list instead of *cons cell*.  The macro `LAST` returns the `cons cell` in a dotted list.  The question asked is to use the macro `reverse` instead of `last`, but both `clisp` and `sbcl` are throwing error.

```
(reverse '(a b c . d))
=> error
```

CLHS documentation says that we can reverse only a proper list (sequence) and not a dotted list or a circular list.

**EDIT**

I have written the program using `LAST`.

```
(defun last-element (x)
 "x is a list with last element as dotted pair"
  (cdr (last x)))
```

I am not sure how to use `reverse` in such a situation.

Comment: Define one on your own?

Comment: I am supposed to define my own function using `reverse`. The chapters related to applicative programming and recursive progragramming are yet to come. Also, thought of using `nthcdr` and `nth`.  But we cannot genarlize it.  I have edited my question. Please refer to that.

Comment: As a side-note, it's rather important to understand that `last`, `reverse` &c are *functions*, not macros.  This difference is very important to understanding Lisp.  In particular it's worth thinking about why you can't write, say, `reverse` as a macro.  You may not know enough to see why yet, but bear this in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `last` returns the last `cons` cell for any proper list or dotted list, so long as the list is not circular.

It sounds like the question is about Exercise 6.6:

> Use the LAST function to write a function called LAST-ELEMENT that returns the last element of a list instead of the last cons cell. Write another version of LAST-ELEMENT using REVERSE instead of LAST. Write another version using NTH and LENGTH.

The exercise would have specified dotted list input if that was the intention. [When *list* is used in an unqualified way, it almost always means *proper list*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_list.htm). For a proper list `last` will return a `cons` cell with `nil` in the `cdr`, e.g., `(last '(a b c d)` -->  `(d . nil)`, or just `(d)`, so the last element of a proper list is the `car` of the last `cons` cell.

If you want to handle both proper and dotted lists, you need to determine which the input is and handle it accordingly: for a dotted list the last "element" would be the `cdr` of the last `cons` cell. Handling the inputs accordingly for the `reverse` version means that you must determine whether the input is a proper list or a dotted list before applying `reverse`. You could write a function to convert a dotted list to a proper list before using `reverse`.

Technically speaking, [the Standard does not consider the atom which terminates a dotted list to be one of its elements](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_e.htm#element):

> element n. 1. (of a list) an object that is the car of one of the conses that comprise the list.

For a proper list like `(a b c d)`, `nil` is the terminating atom (since `(a b c d)` is identical to `(a b c d . nil)`), and `(d . nil)` is the last cons; `d` is the `car` of the last `cons`, and is thus the last element of the list. For a dotted list like `(a b c . d)`, `d` is the terminating atom, and `(c . d)` is the last `cons`. Since `c` is the `car` of the last `cons`, `c` is the last true *element*, in the sense defined in the Standard, of the dotted list. It would probably be more accurate to say that `d` is the last *member* of `(a b c . d)`.

But, Exercise 6.6 in *Common Lisp: A Gentle Introduction* is meant for proper lists only.

Comment: Thank you.  That was exactly the confusion.  Exercise 6.6 mentions that `LAST` returns `cons cell` and asked us to write a function `LAST-ELEMENT` which returns **last element**. So, naturally, I thought the input list will end with  `dotted-pair`.  It was my misunderstanding.  Now, I have to worry about converting a improper list (dotted list) to a proper list. Thanks again.

Comment: So, if the result is `NIL`, what is the purpose of this exercise?

Comment: @SreekumarR -- "_if the result is `NIL`..._": the last element of a proper list is not `nil`. For `(a b c d)` the last element is `d`, and `nil` is the terminating atom.

Comment: Ok. I think I need to get more grasp into lisp. But the question asks to return `last-element` while `last` is returning it already. I am confused. @exnihilo could you please explain to me the question.

Comment: @SreekumarR -- The question wants `last-element` to return the last element of a list: a _proper list_. The `last` function returns the last `cons` of a list, not the last element of that list. The last element of a list is the `car` of the last `cons` of that list. Actually, `last` can take an integer argument and return the last `n` `cons`es of a list. IAC, the last `cons` of `'(a b c d)` is the `cons` `'(d . nil)`, and the last element is `(car '(d . nil))` which is `d`. `nil` is not an element of the list, neither is `'(d . nil)`.

Comment: @SreekumarR -- the list `'(a b c d)` _is_ just a sequence of `cons`es; it is identical to `'(a b c d . nil)`, but `nil` is not an element of the list

Comment: Thanks a lot for not only clarifying the question but also for the explanation.  This was my initial thinking while learning but `dotted list` in some of the previous examples in the book made me to confuse.